# Some reason to use 0007 instead of 7? (16-base)

Tags: assembly, coding-style, hex

I'm reading the source code of older programs,including OS etc all almost in assembly language.

They use e.g:

```
MOV BX,0007
```

note the `0007`

I'm seeing that such practice is very common for assembly programmers(in this epoch?) why not use just 7? is there some special reason? I think that for readability.. maybe?

btw,all numbers for this assembly language is (until I see,isn't document) is assumed to be 16-base.

also,I'm sure on tags. edit for me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no technical reason, but it can be helpful to quickly identify where the 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit numbers are in the code at a glance.

Comment: How many slow is you? [/sarcasm] Thank you so much,@Carl Norum!

Comment: I did mean that you have answered it too quickly. My english is bad :( off-topic: Was you one-of apple's employees?

Comment: No problem - I'm sure you can google whatever you need to know. :-)

Comment: I'm doing it. Are you online on some room at caht.stackoverflow.com?